# How to retrieve values from ArrayList<String> if the latter is a Key in Map?

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary

I am new to Java. Now I'm trying to work with a structure like

```
 Map<List<String>,String>
```

..and there are difficulties with retrieving Strings from the List.

Details: 
I am making a simple program which takes phone numbers and checks to which country specific number belongs. It checks them via matching with regular expressions (underlying digit amount and international prefix: because prefixes (and thus - regular expressions) may be more then one - List is chosen).

So, the structure of regex is:

```
"^(%s)\\d{%d}", prefix, digitAmount
```

There are some basic data for some numbers (Finnish, English), but user can also add new ones (example: Gonduras - prefix: 849, number of digits: 8, Gonduras (same) - prefix 49, number of digits: 7 etc.) 
So when you will enter a number like 893143045839 - it should find whether it matches regular expression. And if it is, return the country (a value). That's why the Map is chosen.

The code here is:

```
static Map <List<String>, String> data = new HashMap<List<String>, String>();
static List<String> newdata = new ArrayList<String>();

void addBasicData ()  // here I add some predefined parameters
{
List<String> finnNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
finnNumbers.add("^(3589)\\d{6}");
finnNumbers.add("^(003589)\\d{6}");
finnNumbers.add("^(09)\\d{6}");
data.put(finnNumbers, "Finland");
}


void addNewData (String pattern, List<String> newdata)   //here I add new data from user
{
pattern();
data.put(newdata, pattern);
}
```

The problem occurs further. When I want to check some number, I have to make a pattern - which should take the regex from the data. Well, it appears that I can't. 
Here is the method..

```
void numberCheck (String inputNumber)
{

// maybe I'll use Set values = data.keySet(); ? ...nah, doesn't work either :(


for (int i = 0; i<= data.size(); i++)
{
    Object c = data.get(i);
    List<String> check = (List<String>)c;
    for (int j = 0; j <check.size(); j++)   
    {

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(check.get(j));
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(inputNumber);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            // some useful code
        }

    }


}
```

.., which do not work and gives NullPointerException. When I want to take a key and then try each regex as a pattern, it instead gives me an Object, not an ArrayList. That's why I am asking.
I tried to use it reverse-like ( Map> ), but then I need to iterate values, and there is the same problem.

This is the point

```
    Object c = data.get(i);
    List<String> check = (List<String>)c;
```

, where everything collapses. 
Perhaps, I'm doing it entirely wrong and should use another classes in my case.

I would be glad, if anyone can give an advice. Thank you!

Comment: You have a `Map<List<String>, String>`. The keys of the map are thus `List<String>` instances. An `Integer` is not a `List<String>`. So calling `data.get(i)` where i is an Integer will never get you anything. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. A Map doesn't seem like the appropriate data structure here.

Comment: I am trying to iterate the Map. To take first (i = 1) ArrayList (key) and check whether it matches, then second (i =2) etc. Like in case of arrays. I will now look more precisely how to iterate collections correctly.

Comment: About a data structure: perhaps not. I haven't figured out yet what structure should I use instead.

The logic is simple:
1. user types a number: 7941949394
2. this number goes as an input to the method which checks whether it matches some regex (which is one of the keys to a value)
3. if it matches (for instance "^(79)\\d{8}") - then it should return a country

Comment: Why don't u hv map like Map<String, List<String>> where key is country  and value is list of phone numbers

Comment: I tried to reverse it, but how could I retrieve values without a key (there is no information about the country, only a number from input). I mean, it would be the same in the end: I should retrieve all values (in this case) and match

Comment: Seems to me you are not doing a key / value lookup. Seems to me you are iterating the Map to test all possible values. So per Ankit's suggestion, use a `Map<String, List<String>>` (or better a `Multimap`) and iterate the `Entries` via `entrySet()`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()

Answer (score 2):

I guess thats what you want to do

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
// ...some more code...
for (List<String> regexNumbers : map.values()) {
    // regexNumbers is the value
}
```

Since you dont use the key in your method.

But your code whould be much more readable if you create a class - thats your structure, thats what you want, and you know (!) whats in it (even in a few years):

```
class CountryNumbers {
    String country;
    List<String> numbers;
}
```

Examplecode to print every number to a country:

```
List<CountryNumbers> list = fillListSomehow();
for (CountryNumbers countryNumbers : list) {
    String country = countryNumbers.country;
    System.out.println("The regexes for country " + country + " are: ");
    for (String regexNumber : countryNumbers.numbers) {
        System.out.println("  " + regexNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should iterate `entries` not `values` so that he has the key / Country when a match is found. Agree with suggest for `CountryNumbers`. Would suggest adding method `numberMatches` to `CountryNumber`.

Comment: FYI, use Multimap instead of Map<T, List<V>>: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: Thank you, guys!

to Sneaker182: Sounds like good idea. This program is very tiny, yet it could be good just for OOP standards. So far I have created 2 classes: NumCheck and Main (Main for a GUI and running). In the checking one - methods for checking numbers and, perhaps, event listeners. I am also thinking about how to save new data to some file (what file format should I choose to save collection (or object), for retrieving it after the next start of the program), but it will be later. to JohnB: I never worked with other libraries, like guava (knowing little about them), but I'll look there

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

`static Map <List<String>, String> data = new HashMap<List<String>, String>();`

You should do

`static Map <String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();`

Then, down when you are trying to go through the values

```
void numberCheck (String inputNumber)
{


    String[] keys = (String[]) data.keySet().toArray();
for (int i = 0; i<= keys.length; i++)
{
    List<String> check = (List<String>)data.get(keys[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j <check.size(); j++)   
    {

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(check.get(j));
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(inputNumber);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            // some useful code
        }

    }


}
}
```

It will actually return a List. By calling `data.get(i)` you are asking for the VALUE of the data set at index `i` in the Map.

Comment: It's not me (I even have no right to vote : ))
Thank you! I will try that soon

Comment: You are still using an `Integer` to look up a value where all the keys are `String`. This means you will never get a value. Sadly the map interface defines `get()` as taking an `Object` instead of an instance of the key type.

Comment: -1 see unholy's comment. A `Map` is not a list. You don't iterate it by passing an index. Instead you use `entrySet`.